# How can I do it with for loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

when I excute this command

```
cd /D "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.REPORTING_1"
```

it works fine, the '*' is replaced

but when I work with for loop  the '*' isn't replaced

```
for /L %%a in (1, 1, 2) do (
  cd /D "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.REPORTING_%%a"
  set ffile=%cd%
)
```

Comment: If I have a look at my firefox appdata subdirs I don't find anything similar, you should show a sample of the dirs you want to iterate over. Tree.exe is still helpful for that.

Comment: IMO there is a backslash missing in front of the asterisk

Comment: this is "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\*.REPORTING_1" change to this "C:\Users\khalid\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\*.R‌​EPORTING_1", and that folder I created it defult folder there is "C:\Users\khalid\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\*.d‌​efault" and the '*' should be replaced by a string Mozilla creates it

Comment: it was deleted when I posted it, I redited it

Comment: You should read the [help on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Indent code with 4 spaces. It's still unclear to me what the real folder names you want to iterate look like. If you don't want to expose your profile then neutralize it.

Comment: This is the folder C:\Users\khalid\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\nyq7bebl.default

Comment: Use the FOR /D command to find the folder.

Comment: I tried that but when I execute, somehow it delete D , and execute only this  "for / %a in (1,1,8) do...."

Answer (score 0):

Your Firefox profile may be found in that location, as are most *.default folders, however that is not the only place they can be found and each user can have several of them.
The good news though is that their locations are defined in a specific file at a specific location.

The following example code should, *(untested)*, output each ProfilePath by searching that known file and may help you with your problem.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal
Set "PF=%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\"
If Not Exist "%PF%" GoTo :EndIt
Set i=0
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In (
    'FindStr/R "^Path=[A-Z]*" "%PF%Profiles.ini"') Do (Set "FP=%%B"
    Call :Sub "%%FP:/=\%%")
Set PP[
:EndIt
Echo( Press any key to exit...
Timeout -1 1>Nul
Exit/B
    :Sub
    Set/A i+=1
    If Exist "%PF%%~1\" (Set PP[%i%]="%PF%%~1") Else (Set PP[%i%]="%~1")
```

Each ProfilePath is set as a variable, e.g. %PP[1]%, %PP[2]%, %PP[3]%…etc.

Comment: Not a direct answer to my question, however I changed everything so that I can use your example and IT WORKED, Thanks a lot (y)